# TWRP mount storage

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp

I am using Lenovo A6000,I am unable to mount storage, system etc. in twrp , i have no os installed only twrp.[image] I checked some posts here about formatting and then wiping and changing parition type...but none ssems to work . how can I mount to internal storage so I can flash custom os... I have checked backup in twrp it shows some folder like boot, system image etc data is present upto 2gb but nothing in /system folder. please HELP

Comment: Sure looks like your internal eMMC storage chip (internal storage) is corrupt or defective... Especially since ALL partitions are showing the same result. If you have the correct TWRP and current version and it is doing this, your device is likely bricked and not repairable with normal software means and would need jtag programming with an official image to recover it, assuming the eMMC chip itself is not defective (which is quite likely actually).

Comment: @acejavelin I think it's way out of my league to do that...so may be I will leave Thank you for reply I would do it was a simple and not much hard...tell me if  it is doable that I can do according to  given instructions..that's what only I am good given my knowledge about this.

Comment: Jtag programming requires special hardware and physical access to the chip... Typically you would send it off to a service to do it. You can purchase the hardware yourself for $150-$400, from vendors like cellcorner.com (as an example). You would likely need a universal one as I don't see a Lenovo specific unit, so you're pushing the upper limits of the price range. Then you would get into the situation of having to find a flashable image, which Lenovo does not offer to the general public. At that point, it is probably better just to replace the device imho.

Comment: actually I was messed installing custom os since then i am getiing this. sure it is hardware? can it be solved anyway...I tried using fastboot recovery.img but the same unable to mount arguments showup in oem android recovery also...I am asking becos its my fav and first one hope it can be mounted by some formatting or adb method

Comment: I can't be positive, but it looks like the partition table is borked (yes, technical term) and unless you can get an official way of restoring the device to stock, the chances it will be recoverable are slim. Is there an XDA forum for this device? If so, I would ask there as this would be a very device specific answer and not really an Android thing.

Comment: Yeah Lenovo A6000 forum is there...https://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-a6000